# Showing that an equation has only one real solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that the equation $\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}=2\arctan{x}$ has only one real solution $x=x_0$, and that $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3} < x_0 < 1$.

As I have gathered, $-\pi<2\arctan{x} < \pi$ and the arctan-function is strictly increasing.

I tried to make a function $f(x)=2\arctan{x}-\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$ and find the derivative but it didn't lead me anywhere... I got $f'(x)=\frac{1+3x^2+2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$, but I didn't find a way to shorten it. I guess it is impossible anyway, since I wasn't asked for a exact solution.

Perhaps it has something to do with inverse functions, since the derivative of $\arctan{x}$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and the derivative of $\tan{x}$ is $1+tan^2{x}$ which can be written as $1+y^2$ if $y=\tan{x}$...

Comment: You need not shorten it; you need to put bounds on that derivative.

Comment: You were on the right track since $3x^2+2x+1=0$ does not show any real root. So $f(x)$ is an increasing function and it has only one root. Now, just check the values at the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f'(x)>0$. So, $f$ is strictly increasing, and therefore the equation $f(x)=0$ can have *at most* one solution. Besides$$f\left(\frac{\sqrt3}3\right)=\frac{4\pi-9-3\sqrt3}{12}<0\quad\text{and}\quad f(1)=\frac\pi2-1>0.$$So, the equation $f(x)=0$ has a solution in $\left(\frac{\sqrt3}3,1\right)$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the reasoning. It wasn't that difficult then...

Comment: I'm glad I could help.